# php inside javascript alternative

Tags: javascript, php

In the code below after user click in cancel button It will call the function `botao_excluir()`. Inside of this function I want to run the `cancela_cielo()` php function. But I know that is impossible to run PHP inside JavaScript. So Could someone please tell me a way to do this?

### PHP

```
<?php
 $id=$row['id_temp_transaction'];
  if($row['status']!=9)
  {
  echo "<input type = \"button\" name=\"cancel\" value = \"Cancel\" onclick=     \"botao_excluir()\" >";
  }
?>
```

### JavaScript

```
<script>
function botao_excluir()
{
    var r=confirm("Press OK to confirm the cancel")
    if (r==true)
    {
        <?php cancela_cielo($row['tid'], $row['numero_afiliacao'], $row['chave_utilizada']); ?>
        alert("Transaction Canceled")
    }
    else
    {
     alert("Cancel aborted")
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you could use ajax for that

Comment: You need to learn about ajax: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ajax 
this will send the request to **page.php** as example the request will be executed in php and the data will be returned.

```
function botao_excluir()
{
    var r=confirm("Press OK to confirm the cancel")
    if (r==true)
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
        xhr.open("POST","page.php",false);
        xhr.send();
        // response will be assigned to data variable
        data = xhr.responseText
        alert("Transaction Canceled")
    }
    else
    {
     alert("Cancel aborted")
    }
}
```

you can read more about ajax and php here
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_php.asp